# Long term tracking AWS lambda executions

Tags: aws-lambda

In the AWS Lambda console, I can see number of invocations for last 7 days only.   Specifically, I got my first Alexa skill certified, and I want to keep long term stats on usage (it was implemented as a NodeJS Lambda function).  Is there any way to see data for last 30 days? What would I need to do to preserve data on a longer basis.  I can see several potential options:

1) something built-in in AWS that I haven't explored or learned yet

2) writing code to copy/summarize existing log data

3) adding my own tracking to my AWS Lambda functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The charts you see in the Lambda console are simple views of the metrics for your Lambda function that are maintained in AWS CloudWatch. You can view the same data in the CloudWatch console, and CloudWatch retains 15 months of data. So without making any code changes or integrating with any new services or anything, just changing the console you are looking at, you can go from only having 7 days of data in your view to 15 months of data.

Comment: Thanks, I created a graph and saved it as a dashboard.  What if I was at a client and they wanted to keep 3 or 5 years of stats?

Comment: @NealWalters you would need to export those metrics via API calls if you needed to keep more than 15 months.

Answer (score 1):

You can export Log Data to S3 from which you can download it if needed or query it using Athena.

Documentation: Exporting Log Data to Amazon S3

Comment: Fixed. Thanks @NealWalters.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Mark's Answer if you need to retain your logs for a longer period, you can consider streaming your logs from cloudwatch to an elastic search cluster and use Kibana as your visualization layer.

Check out this [webinar](https://youtu.be/PFUcF9Ye0fc) from Aws for more details.